# i would like the button to be displayed 30 seconds to the end of the video regardless of the length

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

The code below doesn't seem to be working. The button doesn't display at all. I had tried using delay but it doesn't work as I would have liked

```js
$(document)
            .ready(
                function() {
                    $(document).on("timeupdate", "#video3", function() {
                        var videoElem = $("#video3")[0];
                        console.log(videoElem.duration);
                        if (((parseInt(videoElem.duration - videoElem.currentTime)) <= 30)){
                            $('.btn3d.').show();
                        } else {
                            $('.btn3d.').hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
            );
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>Students/introduction" style="float: left;">
      <video id="video3" width="640" height="360" controls>
        <source src="/elearning/assets/videos/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video> <br>
      <input style="display: none;" type="submit" id="btn3d" value="Proceed" class="btn btn-primary btn3d">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have too many (( in the if

If the video is static and not inserted dynamically you can change

```
$(document).on("timeupdate", "#video3", function() {
```

to

```
$("#video3").on("timeupdate", function() {
```

In any case try this toggle

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("timeupdate", "#video3", function() {
    var videoElem = this;
    console.log(videoElem.duration);
    $('#btn3d').toggle(parseInt(videoElem.duration - videoElem.currentTime) <= 30);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>Students/introduction" style="float: left;">
  <video id="video3" width="640" height="360" controls>
    <source src="/elearning/assets/videos/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video> <br>
  <input style="display: none;" type="submit" id="btn3d" value="Proceed" class="btn btn-primary btn3d">
</form>
```